# Flex - Search in ArrayCollection by part of the word

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3

For example i have an ArrayCollection, and i want to find persons with telephone begines with "944" how can i do this?

```
<mx:ArrayCollection id="arrColl" >
    <mx:source>
        <mx:Array>
            <mx:Object telephone="944768" subscriber="Smith P.T."/>
            <mx:Object telephone="944999" subscriber="Peterson Q.T."/>
         </mx:Array>
        </mx:source>
    </mx:ArrayCollection>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you displaying this ArrayCollection as a dataprovider to a user somewhere? If so, then you can set [`arrColl.filterFunction`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#filterFunction) property of the collection and then call `arrColl.refresh()`

Example filter function:

```
function filterTelephoneBeginsWith(item:Object):Boolean
{
   var beginsWithString:String = "944";

   return String(item["telephone"]).indexOf(beginsWithString) == 0;
}
```

If you're just trying to get an Array of all the ones beginning with 944, you can use the same function-- just apply it to every item in `arrColl` to determine whether or not it should be in your resulting Array.